# How to make link to point to view?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In my *application.html.erb* file I have some links and *<%= yield %>*. What I want is when a link is click, a view to be rendered in the *<%= yield %>* field without refreshing the whole page.

So, I started implementing this with ajax but I am doing something wrong and need some help.

This is what I did:

In my webinars_controller.rb *index* method I added *format.js*:

> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   format.html
>   format.js
>   format.json { render json: @webinars }
> end
> ```

Then create *index.js.erb* file in /app/views/webinars/ folder:

```
$('.b-content-container').html("<%=j render @webinars %>");
```

and the following is how I am creating the link in the *application.html.erb* file:

> 

But  clicking on the link I get interal serve error that points me to this code in my *application.js*:

> // Do send the request
>
> // This may raise an exception which is actually
>
> // handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
>
> xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the issue, I have to use the *:template* option of the render [render](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) function to specify the template and *:collection* to pass data to the current template.

> ```
> > <%=j render template:'webinars/index' , collection:@webinars
> > %>
> ```

This still fails, because  in the views folder I have a partial named: *index.js.erb* and somehow rails is not able to understand what I wanted to be rendered, so I need to specify the template extension too:

> ```
> > <%=j render template:'webinars/index.html.erb' , collection:@webinars
> > %>
> ```